# How to create future dates with Month frequency in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a future data frame which contains date with month frequency in an another data frame.

The data I am using is given below dput(date):

```
c("2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01")
```

[image]

The expected result which I was trying to achieve is to create set a frequency which can be mentioned like this,

```
freq = 9
```

and then generates dates for the next 9 months in a data frame, like 2022-09-01 to 2023-09-01?

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `library(lubridate); seq(ymd("2023-09-01"), by=months(1), length.out=9)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options: here's one with `lubridate::months`.

```r
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
  "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
  "2022-08-01") 

max(ymd(dates)) %m+% months(1:9)
#[1] "2022-09-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-11-01" "2022-12-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-02-01" "2023-03-01" "2023-04-01" "2023-05-01"
```

Or with `seq`:

```r
seq(max(ymd(dates)), by = "month", length.out = 9)
```

Or with `clock::add_months`:

```r
library(clock)
add_months(max(ymd(dates)), 1:9)
```